# Is FacesContext limited to one web application?

Tags: jsf, facescontext

I have an ear , Sample.ear and two war files and one jar file  in that 
It's like this

```
  Sameple.ear
     |--- UI1.war
     |--- UI2.war
     |--- Model.jar
```

I have a managed-bean(backing-bean) defined in UI1.war . Is it possible to access that particular managed-bean in  a jsf page inside UI2.war ?

I tired to get it like #{LoginBean.username} (LoginBean is the managed bean inside UI1.war which I want to access )  , in my UI2.war , but FacesContext is not able to resolve this .

Pls help

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah . FacesContext is limited per WAR files.